# Is there a limit to how strong someone can get in the Dragonball universe?

Tags: powers, dragon-ball-z, dragonball-super

It would seem that in Dragonball Z/Super there really is no limit to how strong a fighter can get. Every time Goku reaches a “limit” he’ll break it and become stronger. One of the reasons I gave up watching was that I wanted Jiren to be the limit and the rest of the time; characters would catch up to him. However, they just keep introducing new villains who make Jiren look like a creampuff.

The power ceiling would seemingly be the Grand Minister as he is the Head Angel and Whis’s father. It will take quite some time for Goku to reach that level of strength but then again if you use logic; the hypothetical fusion of Beeris and Whis; Whirrus is likely stronger as is the hypothetical Mastered Ultra Instinct Vegito. That would seemingly answer my question but I recall reading that Granolah (a new character) wished to be the strongest in the universe with the eternal dragon. The Eternal Dragon couldn’t grant it and had to use a loophole by giving him the amount of strength he could gain if he trained to his full poterntial. That implies that each fighter has a limit (no matter how ridiculously high it may be as as Granolah became stronger than Goku).

However, is there any indication that there is a universal limit that no fighter can surpass? There is a logical limit for speed as you can’t move faster than instantaneous. But strength?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What kind of source are you looking for?  How official?  And how are you measuring strength?

Comment: Any source and by power level

Comment: It's been a while since I read the comic, but I don't remember any mention of a limit to power. Of course, this doesn't mean that there isn't an implicit or intended limit.